# escape underscores

Tags: rules

I have to write a format using undescores like this

[image]
But when I put antislash before every one to escape it, it doesn't look nice, the underscores looks seperated

[image]

Is there a solution to escape the hole word

Comment: Depending on your real needs: `\underline{...}` or the various commands from the `soul` package. I wouldn't use `\underline` however as a real typesetting tool ;-). And you mean `backslash`, most likely, i.e. `\_`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest making `\format` to use a sample argument to define the width (plus buffer, in this case 2pt).  For example, `\format{000}` will make the underline the width of "000" plus 2pt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\format}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rule[-.2\baselineskip]{\dimexpr2pt+\wd0}{.4pt}}

\begin{document}

Format (\format{00}) \format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to account for the difference between typeset versus handwritten lettering, one could apply a multiplier to `\wd0`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\format}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rule[-.2\baselineskip]{\dimexpr3pt+1.5\wd0}{.4pt}}

\begin{document}

Format (\format{00}) \format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Set a `\rule` of specified width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\format}[2][-.2\baselineskip]{\rule[#1]{#2}{.4pt}}

\begin{document}

Format (\format{2em}) \format{2em}-\format{2em}-\format{2em}-\format{2em}

\end{document}
```

Some vertical adjustment can be tweaked by trying different lengths. The optional argument to `\format` sets the rule `.2\baselineskip` below the baseline by default.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\format}[2][2pt]{\underline{\hspace{#1}\phantom{#2}\hspace{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Format (\format{000}) \format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}-\format{000}

\end{document}
```

The above option uses an `\underline`d `\phantom` with some padding.